# SQL loop select query in listed database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named *databaselist* in database *universal*.
This table contains all database names on same instance which I am going to select. Each of those databases has table named *customermaster*.

I want to loop a `SELECT` query on all those listed databases and return one result. For example, I want to get list of customers whose `city = "chicago"` from all database which are listed in *databaselist* table of *universal* database.

Comment: It can almost certainly be done; how difficult or easy it will be depends on the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

**Create Table Script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[databaselist]
(
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](100)
)
```

**Insert Script**

```
Insert into [databaselist]([DatabaseName])
Select 'Database_1' union 
Select 'Database_2' union 
Select 'Database_3' union 
Select 'Database_4' union 
Select 'Database_5'
```

**Prepare Script**

```
Declare @City varchar(100)
Set @City='chicago'
decLare @id varchar(8000)
SELECT @id =  COALESCE( @ID + '    union ' ,'  '  )
 +'select * from '+
CAST(DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(5000))+'.dbo.customermaster where city =''' +@City+''''
FROM databaselist 

Print @id 

Exec (@id)
```

**Assumption**

1. customermaster table has an identical structure in all the databases.
2. All the table are using dbo schema.

Comment: @user1041627 please have a look and let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sql server`, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF(
                                (SELECT CONCAT(' UNION ALL ','SELECT * FROM ',
                                                dbName, '..customermaster ')
                                 FROM databaselist FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 10, ''))

EXEC(@sql)
```

With `dbName` being your column that has the database name.

- provided that the table structure is the same.

Comment: one ques, sameway how can i make update? (instead of select)